# Using rtrim in php for specific purpose

Tags: php, trim

I am not much used to using rtrim and Reg expressions. So I wanted to get my doubt cleared about this:

Here is a url: `http://imgur.com/r/pics/paoWS`

I am trying to use rtrim function on this url to pick out only the 'paoWs' from the whole url.
Here is what i tried:

```
$yurl = 'http://imgur.com/r/pics/paoWS';
$video_id = parse_url($yurl, PHP_URL_PATH);

$yid=rtrim( $video_id, '/' );
```

And i am using '$yid' to hotlink the image from imgur. But What I get after trying this function is:

```
$yid= '/r/pics/paoWS'
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: How do you solve this?  Not with rtrim, that's for sure.  Can you tell us why you thought rtrim would help you here?

Comment: Do I need to use regular expressions on the url?

Comment: I thought rtrim would trim out the last part which i wanted to hotlink the image.

Comment: @RobbieDc Did you check the API reference docs? http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: No Ben, I think i should now.. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rtrim` is used for trimming down a string of certain characters or whitespace on the right-hand side. It certainly shouldn't be used for your purpose.

Assuming the URL structure will always be the same, you could just do something like this:

```
$yurl = 'http://imgur.com/r/pics/paoWS'; 
$video_id = parse_url($yurl, PHP_URL_PATH);
$parts = explode('/', $video_id)
$yid = end($parts);
```

Answer (score 2):

You sould not use regular expressions (whitch are 'expensive') for a so 'simple' problem.

If you want to catch the last part of the URL, after the last slash, you can do :

```
$urlParts = explode('/', 'http://imgur.com/r/pics/paoWS');
$lastPart = end($urlParts);
```

Comment: This will trigger an E_STRICT notice. You must assign the return value of `explode()` and then use `end()` on the produced variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
rtim( strrchr('http://imgur.com/r/pics/paoWS' , '/') );   rtrim + strrchr
substr(strrchr('http://imgur.com/r/pics/paoWS', "/"), 1);  substr + strrchr
```

Answer (score 1):

`rtrim()` returns the filtered value, not the stripped characters. And your usage of it isn't proper too - it strips the passed characters from the **right** side. And you don't need `parse_url()` either.
Proper answers have been given already, but here's a faster alternative:

```
$yid = substr($yurl, strrpos($yurl, '/')+1);
```

Edit: And another one:

```
$yid = ltrim(strrchr($yurl, '/'), '/');
```